# Getting the Raspberry Pi compatible with the IFTTT Maker channel

Tags: webserver, raspberry-pi, iot, webiopi

I'm really wondering what would be an efficient way to control your gpios or run scripts with the new ifttt.com/maker channel. It's really easy to trigger something from the raspberry pi, you just curl the given event url and then you trigger your action. The other way around is a bit more complicated for me.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/06fog.jpg

So I tried set up a server with WebIOPI, which works great but not really for what I planned for. It basically connects with your weaved.com account. What do you think what would be an easy and stable efficient way to trigger my gpios with ifttt?

Answer (score 0):

IFTTT provides Wordpress web hook, it will post to Wordpress app. You can create bridge receive that hook and publish to RPI board by websocket or MQTT.
See:
https://harizanov.com/2015/03/making-ifttt-if-this-then-that-talk-to-node-red/
and nodejs solution: https://github.com/b00giZm/express-ifttt-webhook